# repeat last command but not write

Tags: command-line

`@:` repeats the last colon command I entered, but also seems to include `:write`

so often I go through this kind of workflow:

```
:s/foo/bar
:w
```

Now I go to another line and want to run `:s/foo/bar` again, but `@:` runs `:w` instead.

Can I get `@:` to ignore `:w`?

Comment: IIRC “: is readonly; that said, you might (_might_) be able to accomplish something with a remapping of `@:` by saving the command string in a global var on Enter at command line (but only for : lines, and only if not write (of which there are many variants))

Comment: Write a function named `ExecuteLastNotWrite()` and `map @: :call ExecuteLastNotWrite()<CR>`. In the function get the last entry from the history(`histget("cmd", -1)`). If `:w`, get the second to last. Then execute the fetched command. See `:help histget()`.

Comment: Do you know that you can repeat the last `:s` with `&` (current line) and the last `:%s` with `g&` (run substitute over complete file)?

Answer (score 6):

It seems you basically understand correctly: `":` is a readonly register that contains the last executed command. `@:` will execute this register. Feel free to read up on this: [`:help ":`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#quote:) and [`:help @`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#@).

Further, your issue is that you want to repeat a command but you are issuing a new command in between, `:write`, which obviously overwrites `":`. You ask: "Can I get `@:` to ignore `:w`?". Of course, yes, you can define a new command that uses `histget()` and map it to `@:`, as is suggested by @Ralf in the comments. However, I will advice that you instead reconsider your own workflow. Instead of changing `@:`, try to compose repeatable commands. For instance, instead of

```
:s/foo/bar
:w
```

write

```
:s/foo/bar/e | update
```

Here I've added the `e` flag, which prevents the substitute command from failing if there are no `foo`s found. Then I use `|` ([`:help bar`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#:bar)) to add a new command to be executed after, and I use `:update` instead of `:write` to only write the file if there is a change.

In my opinion, this is a better solution than changing how Vim works.

Comment: that's so long to type out every time, and it relies on me knowing that I will want to repeat a substitute in advance